# obtain the position of an object in an image

Tags: image-processing, object-recognition, position

I would like to compare the positions of the same object in 2 different pictures and get the difference between the positions in in terms of x and y coordinates.Suppose I have a picture with a square figure on it at the centre and then I reposition the square to the top right corner.I would like to find by what distance has the square moved.

Comment: What part of the process are you having trouble with, and what possible solutions have you already looked into? Right now this is rather broad and ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use normalized cross correlation between the images

matlab has an awesome tutorial on the subject:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/registering-an-image-using-normalized-cross-correlation.html

Its very useful to use in situations where it is not as up-front as a rectangle on a black background

Answer (score 0):

If the only change or the main change is just the location of the square, and the background is almost the same you can subtract the two images and then use some threshold to be able to detect the two squares. then compare the $(x,y)$ value for a specific corner of the two squares. If it is $(x1,y1)$ for one and $(x2,y2)$ for the other then the distance is $$\sqrt{((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)}$$.